# How to get just the content of a post from a blog?

Tags: java, javascript, html, rss

I have just the url of a post, like http://www.avc.com/a_vc/2011/08/html5-continued.html ,  is ther any way of get the content of this post? I mean, exclude menus, logos and advertisements.

Thank you very much!

Comment: use RSS feed what is available on this page

Comment: java is to javascript as car is to car :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to scrape the site, first consider whether this is legal.

Then, you can do that be getting the `innerHTML` (or with jQuery - the `.html()`) of the appropriate element. In your case this is `disqus_post_message`

As @bensiu noted it would be easier to use the RSS feed.

Since you tagged Java, here are the libraries that can be useful:

- [HtmlParser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/) for parsing the html
- [Rome](http://java.net/projects/rome/) for RSS

Comment: Thank you bozho! But I already know this two frameworks, the thing is  in this way I should implement a pattern for each website. About the rss Stuff, try to find de rss link and then find the tag that has the same url. The last case looks better but there are hundreds of variations, so i would like to avoid this option if possible.